# Evitar duplicar mi vista previa en modal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

al manda mis datos a la vista previa esta bien, así como al inserta los datos pero al dar al boton "no" este cierra la vista previa lo cual esta bien pero al querer guardar de nuevo en el modal se duplica la información y así sucesivamente ¿como puedo evitar eso ?
[image: vdfgfg]

en esta imagen muestro mi vista previa correcta al dar al boton "no" para regresar al formulario a corregir informacion y volver a guardar me duplica la informacion, solo en el modal ya que al guardar asi solo se guarda una vez no duplica en la base de dato

foto donde duplica la info:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo evitar esto les uestro mi codigo en HTML:

```
 <button type="submit" class="tab-btn-sumbit" id="guardar">Si</button>

 <button type="reset" class="tab-btn-cancel" id="cancelar">No</button>
```

Y MI CODIGO EN JAVASCRIPT :

```
 $(document).on("click","#cancelar",function(e){
 closeModal();
 });
  $(document).on("click","#guardar",function(e){//botones

 $('.cotizador_box').hide();
 $('.loader').show();
 $.ajax({  

   type:"POST",
   url:"<?=URL?>velada/Guardar",        
  data:$('#form-velada').serialize(),
  dataType:"json",   
  success:function(data){ 
   closeModal();
   $('#messages').html(data.message);
   $('#resumen').html(''); 
  }  
  });
  });
```

AYuDA ;V

CODIGO DEL  MODAL:

```
    $(document).on("submit","#form-velada",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $('.cotizador_box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
   $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
   $('.backdrop, .cotizador_box').css('display', 'block');

  html='<p><span>fecha:</span><p>';
  var fecha = $("#letra2").val();
  html+= ""+fecha;

  html+='<p><span>Autorizo:</span><p>';
  var autorizo = $("#autorizo").val();  
  html+= ""+autorizo;

  html+='<p><span>Responsable:</span><p>';
  var responsable = $("#responsable").val();
  html+= ""+responsable; 

  html+='<p><span>Personal:</span><p>';
  var areas = $("select[name='area[]'").map(function(){return 
  $(this).val();}).get(); 
  html+= "Area:   "+areas+"  <br>  ";
  html+='';

  var personal = $("select[name='personal[]'").map(function(){return 
  $(this).val();}).get();
 html+= "Personal:   "+personal;

    html+='<p><span>Ordenes:</span><p>';

   var descripcion = $("input[name='descripcion[]'").map(function(){return 
   $(this).val();}).get();

  var ODT = $("input[name='clave[]'").map(function(){return 
  $(this).val();}).get();

  html+= "Descripción:   "+descripcion+"   ";
  html+='<br>'; 
 html+= "ODT:   "+ODT;

 html+='<p><span>Gastos:</span><p>'; 
 var gasto = $("select[name='tipo_gasto[]'").map(function(){return 
 $(this).val();}).get();

var costo = $("input[name='costo[]'").map(function(){return 
$(this).val();}).get();

html+= "Gastos:   "+gasto+"   ";
 html+='<br>';
 html+= "Costo:   "+costo;

  $('#resumen').append(html);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El motivo por el cual se duplica la información es porque nunca borras la que ya existe en el Modal. Para esto puedes usar la función 
[.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) de Jquery.

Viendo tu código, hay dos lugares en las que se puede implementar:

1.- En el apartado donde detectas que se da clic al botón "No" del Modal

```
$(document).on("click","#cancelar",function(e){
    $('#resumen').empty();
    closeModal();
});
```

2.- Antes de agregar la información que mostraras en el Modal.

```
$(document).on("submit","#form-velada",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    ...

    $('#resumen').empty().append(html);
});
```

Comment: Considera que utilizo los tres puntos ("...") para no reescribir todo tu código

Comment: muchas gracias hermano le hice de mil maneras y no agarraba solo era eso que nub soy ;v

Comment: De nada @JooelMcCready, y créeme que todos pasamos por esa etapa, pero conforme desarrollas proyectos, vas aprendiendo mas y mas.